# How To add different Chrome Custom tab toolbar colors for multiple websites in one app?

Tags: android-studio, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using the Chrome Custom tab in my android app to open multiple websites, so I want to keep different toolbar colors for each website, so kindly help me how to do that?